# ESP32-CAM interfacing with CCS811+HDC1080+BMP280

Tags: esp8266, esp32, espressif

I want to measure Temprature, Pressure, Humidity and CO2 in a room with ESP32-CAM & [CCS811+HDC1080+BMP280](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32871484471.html)

Since this module is combination of 3 sensors. Can I integrate it with ESP32-CAM over Software SPI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Those three devices are I2C devices, not SPI devices.

Using that is no different to using three individual sensors all wired to the same I2C bus.